# Prove that $\int \limits_{E}fd\mu=\int \limits_{X}f\chi_{E}d\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu)$ be measure space. Let $f\geq 0$ be measurable function. Prove the following equality: $$\int \limits_{E}fd\mu=\int \limits_{X}f\chi_{E}d\mu$$

I can show only that $\int \limits_{E}sd\mu=\int \limits_{X}s\chi_{E}d\mu$ for simple function $s$.

Can anyone show the full proof please?

Comment: Couldn't you just use $\int_X g \mathrm{d} \mu = \int_{E} g \mathrm{d} \mu + \int_{X \setminus E} g \mathrm{d} \mu $?

Comment: And btw, $E$ is measurable?

Comment: Yes $E$ is measurable. No I can't use this property

Comment: How is $\int_Efd\mu$ defined then?

Comment: @drhad, It's defined as supremum over all simple fubctions $s$ such that $0\leqslant s\leqslant f$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of attempts I solved above problem:

Let $s$ be a simple function such that $0\leqslant s\leqslant f$. Then $0\leqslant s\chi_E\leqslant f\chi_E$. Hence $\int \limits_{X}s\chi_Ed\mu\leqslant\int \limits_{X}f\chi_Ed\mu.$ But since $\int \limits_{X}s\chi_Ed\mu=\int \limits_{E}sd\mu$. Then $$\int \limits_{E}sd\mu\leqslant\int \limits_{X}f\chi_Ed\mu,$$ which is true for any simple function $s$ with $0\leqslant s\leqslant f$. Then $$\int \limits_{E}fd\mu\leqslant\int \limits_{X}f\chi_Ed\mu \qquad (*)$$
Let $t$ be a simple function with $0\leqslant t\leqslant f\chi_E$. Then $t=t\chi_E$. Then $$\int \limits_{E}td\mu=\int \limits_{E}t\chi_Ed\mu.$$
But LHS is equal to $\int \limits_{X}t\chi_Ed\mu=\int \limits_{X}td\mu$. Then $$\int \limits_{E}f\chi_Ed\mu=\int \limits_{X}f\chi_Ed\mu \qquad (**)$$ Using estimate $(*), (**)$ and $f\chi_E\leqslant f$ we get: $$\int \limits_{E}fd\mu\leqslant\int \limits_{X}f\chi_Ed\mu=\int \limits_{E}f\chi_Ed\mu\leqslant \int \limits_{E}fd\mu.$$
Hence $\int \limits_{E}fd\mu=\int \limits_{X}f\chi_Ed\mu$

Answer (score 1):

For the remainder of the proof, just notice that you can approximate any non-negative, measurable function $f$ by an increasing sequence of simple functions $(s_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. Then, use monotone convergence for the integrals to conclude.

Solution without monotone convergence for the integral: Notice that
$$\int_E f
= \sup\{\int_E s\colon s\le f\}
= \sup\{\int_X s\chi_E\colon s\le f\}\\
= \sup\{\int_X r\colon r=s\chi_E \le f\chi_E\}
= \int_X f\chi_E.$$
For the third step, we consider both inequalities seperately:

“$\le$” Let $(s_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence with $s_n\le f$ maximizing $\int_X s\chi_E$. Then, we have $s_n\chi_E\le f\chi_E$, so all $s_n\chi_E$ are allowed in the definition for calculating $\int_X f\chi_E$. Hence,
$$LHS = \sup\{\int_X s\chi_E \colon s\le f\} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X s_n\chi_E \le \sup\{\int_X r\colon r\le f\chi_E\} =RHS.$$

“$\ge$” Let $(r_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence with $r_n\le f\chi_E$ maximizing $\int_X r$. Notice that $r_n=r_n\chi_E$. Moreover, we have $r_n\le f$, so all $r_n$ are allowed in the definition for calculating $\int_E f$. Hence,
$$RHS=\sup\{\int_X r \colon r\le f\chi_E\} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X r_n \le \sup\{\int_X s\chi_E\colon s\le f\}=LHS.$$

Comment: Monotone convergence theorem in Rudin RCA goes after this

Comment: What are you allowed to use? How do you define the integral?

Comment: Integral is defined as supremum over all non-negative functions $s$ such that $s \leqslant f$

Comment: I adapted my answer to your comment.

Comment: Can you show in detail your third step, please?